# What's wrong with this Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This is my code:

```
var coordinateTratte = doc.Descendants(ns + "Folder").First().Descendants(ns + "Folder")
    .Descendants(ns + "Placemark").Select(n =>              
    {
        string[] coordinates = n.Descendants(ns + "coordinates").First().Value.Split(' ');
        foreach (var coordinate in coordinates)
        {
            var coordinateLatLng = coordinate.Split(',');
            return new
            {
                latitude = coordinateLatLng.Last(),
                longitude = coordinateLatLng.First()
            };
        }
    });
```

and it says near `n =>` that some values could not be expressed as Lambda expression.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please don't explain what the error message means, post the *actual* error message.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't there a `new` keyword missing at `n => { ...}` to initialize a new anonymous object?

Comment: @Serv That's not what the code is trying to do. The `{ ... }` is just a regular anonymous function body, not an attempt to create any object.

Comment: Why is he assigning the properties latitude and longitude then?

Comment: @Serv *That* is an attempt to create an anonymous object, inside that anonymous function, and does contain the `new` before it: `return new { latitude = ..., longitude = ... };`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your lambda expression tries to return items "piecemeal" using a loop, while `Select` expects it to return the whole thing at once.

You can fix your code in several ways - for example, you could convert your `foreach` loop to a `Select`, and use `SelectMany`, like this:

```
var coordinateTratte = doc.Descendants(ns + "Folder").First().Descendants(ns + "Folder")
    .Descendants(ns + "Placemark").SelectMany(n =>
    { //                                 ^^^^
        string[] coordinates = n.Descendants(ns + "coordinates").First().Value.Split(' ');
        return coordinates
           .Select(coordinate => coordinate.Split(','))
           .Select(coordinateLatLng => new
            {
                latitude = coordinateLatLng.Last(),
                longitude = coordinateLatLng.First()
            });
    });
```

> I want to return an object such as `Dictionary<string,List<object>>` where object is latitude and longitude

You can change the code like this:

```
var coordinateTratteDict = doc.Descendants(ns + "Folder").First().Descendants(ns + "Folder")
    .Descendants(ns + "Placemark").Select((n,i) =>
    {
        string[] coordinates = n.Descendants(ns + "coordinates").First().Value.Split(' ');
        return new {
            Index = i
        ,   CoordList = coordinates
           .Select(coordinate => coordinate.Split(','))
           .Select(coordinateLatLng => new
            {
                latitude = coordinateLatLng.Last(),
                longitude = coordinateLatLng.First()
            })
            .ToList()
        };
    })
    .ToDictionary(p => "Block_"+p.Index, p => p.CoordList);
```

Comment: Seems to works! But what if I want to return an object such as dictionary? <string> <object> where object is latitude and longitude?

Comment: Can you give to me an example?

Comment: Yes, key is whatever string I want.

Comment: Is it enough? Or did you ask to me other informations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71338/discussion-between-markzzz-and-dasblinkenlight).